# number of RDP sessions on windows server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-xp, remote-access, rdp

Hey, Sorry if this is a dupe. I looked but google was spammed with registry-hack answers.

I need to have multiple users able to RDP into a computer on out LAN. Windows XP/7 seem to only allow one used logged in at a time. Either locally or remotely. What about win server? Can I have up to 10 simultaneous users logged in and active? Sorry, I come from the unix side where this is somewhat trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you purchase the correct licenses and set Windows up as a [Remote Desktop Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services) (Terminal Services)  it works fine with 10 or many more users, assuming you good enough hardware.

You need the Window Server licenses, the Windows Server client access licenses if you don't have any already, and you need Terminal Server access licenses.

Comment: +1 - we've had 100+ users logged into a single Server 2003 box